# Missing dependency org.bouncycastle in spring-security 5.2

Tags: spring-security

Iam using spring-security 5.2.0, specifically Argon2PasswordEncoder. In the documentation they state that it requires BouncyCastle. However in my maven project  the BouncyCastle is not downloaded when I add the spring-security dependency. Also in the maven repository the dependency is not listed, which I don't understand:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/5.2.0.RELEASE

I expected that all dependencies of a library should be listed, at least as Optional, right? is there any explanation for this? My code works when explicitly adding the BouncyCastle dependency in my pom.xml, but I find this unrelialble, as how would I know that I selected the correct version of BouncyCastle?

Comment: There is an issue on GitHub about this : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7805

Comment: Thanks for pointing out